# Oracle DB - create new employee table with latest data based on date

Tags: database, oracle, common-table-expression

Since i'm new to Oracle SQL i'm in need of help.
I wish to create a new employee table in my database - fetching data from my raw table and basing the new data on 'date'.

**EXAMPLE:**
One of my employees have changed last name and i wish to create my table with his/hers latest data entry.

**table1_raw** with
columns **pnbr**; **fname**; **lname**; **date**

```
197001014688 ;Eva   ;Andersson  ;20150501
197001014688 ;Eva   ;Sandsten   ;20160501
198401011133 ;Peter ;Larsson    ;20150102
198401011133 ;Peter ;Larsson    ;20160102
194408011237 ;Sven  ;Hansson    ;20130203
```

**table2** with
columns **pnbr**; **fname**; **lname**; **date**

```
197001014688 ;Eva   ;Sandsten   ;20160501
198401011133 ;Peter ;Larsson    ;20160102
194408011237 ;Sven  ;Hansson    ;20130203
```

In SQL Server i've used the following query, with Common Table Expressions:

```
;WITH CTE as
(SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pnbr ORDER BY date DESC),
  pnbr,
  fname,
  lname
FROM table1_raw)
SELECT
  fname,
  lname,
  pnbr
INTO 
  table2
FROM
  CTE
WHERE
  RN = 1
```

How do i write this query in Oracle SQL?
Is there a more efficient/easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle your query will look like this -

```
insert into table2 
select t.pnbr, t.fname, t.lname, t.date
from table1 t
inner join (
    select pnbr, max(date) as MaxDate
    from table1 tm
    group by username
) tm on t.username = tm.username 
and t.date = tm.MaxDate
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a table based on a SELECT you need to use `create table as` in Oracle (and standard SQL)

Using `rn = ...` to define a column alias is invalid (standard) SQL as well, you need to use `... AS rn`

And finally, the `;` goes to the end of the statement, not in front of the `with` keyword:

```
create table table2
as
WITH CTE as (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pnbr ORDER BY date DESC) as rn, 
         pnbr,
         fname,
         lname
  FROM table1_raw
)
SELECT fname,
       lname,
       pnbr
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```